# Java app does not start after successful gradle build in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

Simple java libgdx hello world builds sucecssful with gradle(new to gradle) build tool from eclipse, but it does not start.
I.e. I get ton of green buttons in graddle executions tab, and BUILD SUCCESSFUL in console tab. I cant find any errors that something went wrong and application could not start or any runtime errors. Nothing.
All instructions Ive been able to find on internets only tells how to build, none tells how to start the newly built application.

Comment: Try running the command `gradle run` in the project directory.  Build does just that, build the project.

Comment: Thx, I finally got it work, it was exactly gradle run (gradlew run on windows)

Answer (score 0):

If your gradle build is successful and the build script is correct, then the jar or war file which is created as a part of packaging should be under <*actualProjectFolder*>/build/libs/<*yourprojectartifactname*>-<*version*>.jar. I think looking at contents of build folder should give you an idea on what could be wrong.

Comment: No jar or war or anything else, not even "remotely looking like" binary is created in process. However gradle run in project folder actually runs the application.

Answer (score 0):

Thx, I finally got it work, it was exactly gradle run (gradlew run on windows) in the project folder.